# Similar methods to update today's sales, revenue, and profit

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Please help me to refactor. I have two models, `conversion` & `statistic`.
Methods `sales_today, revenue_today, profit_today` in `conversion` model only gets specific info from db.

Statistic model

```
class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base

class << self 

def create_and_update_today(agregate_name, value, network)
  today = find_or_create_by(agregateName: agregate_name, networkName: network)
  today.update(agregateName: agregate_name, date: Date.today, 
                value: value, networkName: network)
end

def sales_today(network)
  total = Conversion.sales_today(network)
  create_and_update_today('salesToday', total, network)
end

def revenue_today(network)
  total = Conversion.revenue_today(network)
  create_and_update_today('revenueToday', total, network)
end

def profit_today(network)
  total = Conversion.profit_today(network)
  create_and_update_today('profitToday', total, network)
end

end
end
```

Conversion model

```
class Conversion < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

def sales_today(network)
  where('DATE(created_at)= ?  AND networkName = ?', Date.today, network).size
end
etc...

end
```

Is there any way to refactor almost similar pieces of code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: which class is this code excerpt from? Could you post the `Conversion` class as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of dynamically defining a bunch of methods, you could just have one method that takes an argument that tells it what kind of work to do:

```
def self.create_or_update_today(kind, network)
  meth = :"#{kind}_today"
  total = Conversion.send(meth, network)

  aggregate_name = "#{kind}Today"

  today = find_or_initialize_by(agregateName: aggregate_name, networkName: network)    
  today.update(date: Date.today, value: total)
end
```

You would call it like this:

```
Statistic.create_or_update_today(:sales, network)
```

(You'll notice I used `find_or_initialize_by` instead of `find_or_create_by`. This way the code will always perform two queries instead of performing three if it's a new record. `update` will create the record of it doesn't exist.)

If you wanted you could still define individual methods, but this way it's much cleaner:

```
def self.sales_today(network)
  self.create_or_update_today(:sales, network)
end

def self.revenue_today(network)
  self.create_or_update_today(:revenue, network)
end

# ...
```

You could also do this with `define_method` in a loop as Devon does, but it would save very few lines while sacrificing a lot of readability and, as britishtea points out, introducing documentation issues.

P.S. Just a tip. Don't use `size` for this:

```
where('DATE(created_at) = ?  AND networkName = ?',
      Date.today, network).size
```

You only want to know how many records there are, but when you do this it fetches all of the data in all of the records and initializes a Conversion object for each, which is really wasteful. Instead of `size`, use Rails' built-in [`count`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/count) method:

```
where('DATE(created_at) = ?  AND networkName = ?',
      Date.today, network).count
```

This will let the database perform the calculation so ActiveRecord only needs to fetch a single number.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Devon's answer. You can put method definitions right in the body of class:

```
class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self 
    [:sales_today, :revenue_today, :profit_today].each do |method_name|
      define_method method_name do |network|
        total = Conversion.send(method_name, network)
        create_and_update_today(method_name.to_s.camelcase(:lower), total, network)
      end
    end

    def create_and_update_today(agregate_name, value, network)
      today = find_or_create_by(agregateName: agregate_name, networkName: network)
      today.update(date: Date.today, value: value)
    end
  end
end
```

Also I've removed aggregate and network names from `#update` call, as they won't update anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some nifty meta-programming to dynamically define the methods.

The code below is slightly modified to show the results, you should find it trivial to change back to suit your needs.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize
    super
    [:sales_today,:revenue_today,:profit_today].each do |m|
       self.class.send(:define_method, m) do |network|
        total = 2 # Conversion.sales_today(network)
        # create_and_update_today(m, total, network)
        do_work(m, total, network)
      end
    end
  end

  def do_work (one, two, three)
    puts "#{one} #{two} #{three}"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

puts "Methods: #{foo.methods}"
foo.sales_today("network 1")
foo.revenue_today("network 2")
foo.profit_today("network 3")
```

Output:

```
Methods: do_work
sales_today
revenue_today
profit_today
nil?
===
```

...

```
sales_today 2 network 1
revenue_today 2 network 2
profit_today 2 network 3
```

Comment: Won't this redefine those class methods every time a new instance of Foo is initialized?

Comment: @Jordan Hmm, I think it will, let me look into this further to see if I can prevent that

Comment: Keep in mind that defining methods dynamically like this, keeps them out of your documentation. You might prefer a little duplication over methods hidden in documentation.